# ms access - when I select a query in vba, column is empty

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

When i write a select statement in vba to grab a column from a query its empty.

i have a query thats joined by multiple tables.

For example if I call `select query.specialcolumn from query where query.id=5` I get a blank back. However, If I view it in the query table I see data for ID=5 with data.

Straight SQL in design mode also produces blanks. Only when I view the query as a whole, I can see data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to post the SQL for the "query" as well please, on the face of it this sounds quite strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you used "query" as the name for your saved query.  And query is a reserved word, see [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#Q).  It's hard predict when reserved words as object names will create problems.  And I'm not confident that name is the problem here.  But I would rule it out first before investigating anything else.

Enclose query in square brackets everywhere it's referenced in the SQL.

```
select [query].specialcolumn from [query] where [query].id=5
```

The square brackets will inform the db engine that query is a database object rather than the reserved word.